# What is the purpose of the colon after the flag in some shell command options?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

See this example, taken from the O'Reilly book *Classic Shell Scripting*:

```
sort -t: -k1,1 /etc/passwd
```

Why is there a `:` after the `t`? It doesn't seem to be needed, nor documented in `man`, but I keep seeing it in examples.

Comment: [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sort+-t%3A+-k1%2C1+%2Fetc%2Fpasswd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the argument to the `-t` option, specifying that fields are separated by colons in the input file.

Comment: Ohhhh boy that is not intuitive to me at all. I see now, but damn. It looks like it's separating the `t` from something, except there's nothing there.

Comment: The tricky part is that if `-:` were a valid option for `sort`, then `-t:` and `-t :` would indeed be evaluated differently.

Comment: @chepner no, because the `-t` option always takes an argument. `sort -tr` is the same as `sort -t r`, **not** the same as `sort -t '' -r`.

Comment: Getting a bit far afield, but I wonder if there are argument-parsing libraries that would let one define `-t` with a *optional* argument, then treat `-t:` as `-t -:` rather than `-t :`? That is, would it prioritize treating `:` as an argument rather than a second option?  I guess that would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

`man sort`:

> **-t, --field-separator=SEP** use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

It is shorthand for `-t ':'`, so, colon is field separator.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there a : after the t? It doesn't seem to be needed, nor documented in man, but I keep seeing it in examples.

It is absolutely documented in the manual.  Here's the key part of [the POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) for `sort`'s `-t` option:

> **-t**  *char*
>       Use *char* as the field separator character; *char* shall not be considered to be part of a field (although it can be included in a
>   sort key). [...]

The `:`, then, is the argument to the `t` option.  The `sort` program will split input lines into fields around that character instead of around whitespace.

Your manual page may present it differently (for example, the GNU `sort` manual documents the standard and (GNU-specific) long options together), but the form you present it has the same meaning to all POSIX-conforming `sort` programs.

Comment: I guess you're right, it's just somewhat unclear given the ordinary purpose of a colon in other contexts....it seems like a value is being assigned to the `-t` flag, like key-value notation i.e. `-t='&'` but with a colon instead of equals, except that's not what's happening.

Comment: @temporary_user_name, the `=` notation applies only to long-form options (i.e. `--field-saparator`), and is a GNU extension, like the long-form options themselves.  Standard option arguments are not separated from the option letter by an `=`, and the `=` is optional for long-form options.  GNU manual pages are written in a way that assumes you know this.